# Extract an element of a tuple and make a column with it combining two colums of diferent tables

Tags: sql, database, datatable

I have 2 tables. One is a production report that contains the code of a product in its tuples. The second table is a master of all the products in the Factory, that contains all the information about a certain product whose primary key is the code of product that appears in the first table. 
I need to make a new table that contains information of both tables, but there is a special dificult part. 
The second table (master) has the quality asociated to a certain product (code). I have to sum all the weights of the products of a certain quality (2nd table), which were made in a certain plant (1st table), in a certain date (1st table).
In summary, I need to extract an element (quality) of a tuple (2nd table) and make a column whose name is the quality itself, and this column has the sum of wights of an type (NOT only the code, is an entire type, I mean, a lot of codes together) of a product with a certain quality .

In VBA I tried to separete with "if" the types of products of a certain quality a sum its weights to make a new column. That is really deoptimized, because I calculed that I have to make around 640 "if" to cover the most important type of products, there are a lot more.

Extract an element of a tuple and make a column with it combining two colums of diferent tables

UPDATE

```
CREATE TABLE production (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, pcode integer, plant TEXT, centre TEXT, rawm REAL, finalproduct REAL, pz INTEGER, week INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE product (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, quality TEXT, cutint TEXT, cutfillet TEXT, state TEXT, species TEXT);
INSERT INTO product VALUES (100, "Pr", "ce", "", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (101, "Ind", "ce", "", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (102, "IndB", "ce", "", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (103, "Pr", "", "ta", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (104, "Ind", "", "ta", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (105, "IndB", "", "ta", "fsh", "as");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (106, "Pr", "", "tb", "fz", "co");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (107, "Ind", "", "tb", "fz", "co");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (108, "IndB", "", "tb", "fz", "co");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (109, "Pr", "hg", "", "fz", "co");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (110, "Ind", "hg", "", "fz", "co");
INSERT INTO product VALUES (111, "IndB", "hg", "", "fz", "co");

INSERT INTO production VALUES (1000, "100", "p1", "c1", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1001, "100", "p1", "c1", 14.1, 10.6, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1002, "104", "p1", "c1", 4.12, 3.23, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1003, "105", "p2", "c4", 25.3, 20.7, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1004, "104", "p2", "c1", 12.41, 9.34, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1005, "104", "p2", "c1", 15.21, 10.74, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1006, "110", "p3", "c4", 4.98, 3.4, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1007, "110", "p1", "c1", 13.61, 11.24, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1008, "111", "p1", "c4", 9.7, 7.2, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1009, "100", "p3", "c7", 23.41, 15.74, 13, 1);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1010, "100", "p3", "c7", 27.1, 21.12, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1011, "100", "p2", "c7", 112.1, 87.24, 62, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1012, "100", "p3", "c3", 94, 64.4, 33, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1013, "101", "p3", "c3", 20.51, 15.4, 10, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1014, "101", "p2", "c3", 32.31, 23.34, 16, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1015, "109", "p1", "c1", 6.61, 3.04, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1016, "109", "p1", "c1", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1017, "109", "p1", "c1", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1018, "111", "p3", "c2", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1019, "106", "p3", "c2", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1020, "106", "p1", "c2", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1021, "107", "p1", "c2", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1022, "108", "p2", "c1", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1023, "103", "p2", "c1", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 3);
INSERT INTO production VALUES (1024, "103", "p2", "c5", 10.1, 8.4, 4, 3);
```

And the query:

```
SELECT species, week, plant, centre, cutfillet, cutint, state, SUM(x.k) AS primium_final_Product
FROM (SELECT pd.id AS c, pd.finalproduct AS k
      FROM production pd JOIN
           product pt
           ON pd.pcode = pt.id
      WHERE pt.quality = "Pr"
      GROUP BY c
     ) AS x JOIN
     production JOIN 
     product
     ON production.pcode = product.id AND
        x.c = production.id AND
        x.c = production.id
GROUP BY plant, centre, species;
```

I'VE TRYNG TO DO THIS TO ADD "Ind" quality to the result table, but did not work:

SELECT species, week, plant, centre, cutfillet, cutint, state, SUM(x.k) AS prim, SUM(y.k1) AS ind FROM (SELECT pd.id AS c, pd.kn AS k FROM production pd JOIN product pt  ON pd.pcode = pt.id WHERE pt.quality = "Pr" GROUP BY c) AS x JOIN (SELECT pd1.id AS c1, pd1.kn AS k1 FROM production pd1 JOIN product pt1 ON pd1.pcode = pt1.id WHERE pt1.quality = "Ind" GROUP BY c1) AS y JOIN production JOIN product ON production.pcode = product.id AND x.c = production.id AND x.c = production.id AND y.c1 = production.id  GROUP BY plant, centre, species;

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic you want, and a database tag.

Comment: I added a code I made in the last hours, I did it only for one quality (look the code), to add the others I've been trying hard but I don't have good results.

Comment: I posted the code to add a second quality to the result table ("Ind") but did not work